# How to draw beyound view translation limits?

Tags: android, graphics, translation, invalidation

The following program draws a pie (partial circle, a sector) while I expect it draw entire (full round) circle. How to draw entire circle?

The code of custom view:

```
public class CentralCircleView extends View {

private Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
{
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

public CentralCircleView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CentralCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 100, circlePaint);
}
}
```

The code of activity:

```
public class TransformsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    CentralCircleView centralCircleView = (CentralCircleView) findViewById(R.id.centralCircleView);
    centralCircleView.setTranslationX(200f);
    centralCircleView.setTranslationY(200f);
    centralCircleView.invalidate();
}
}
```

The code of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>

<com.inthemoon.incubation.CentralCircleView
    android:id="@+id/centralCircleView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it draws. Where is the rest of the circle?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your View has its height set to wrap_content which means you need to implement the method onMeasure() to tell RelativeLayout how big the view wants to be.

Comment: Thank you for this parameter hint, but if I change it's value to `fill_parent`, the result is the same. So the question persists.

Comment: Well, the second issue is that your are drawing the circle at 0,0. On Android, the coordinates of a circle indicate the coordinates of the _center_ of the circle. In your case, you should use drawCircle(100, 100, 100, paint)

Comment: I know that 0,0 is the center of a circle, this is what I wanted. The question is how to obtain full circle, not a sector.

Comment: @SuzanCioc yes it is center of the circle ON YOUR VIEW. And you can't paint outside your view. This is why only a 1/4 of the circle is painted.

Comment: Sorry I can't believe you guys yet. Will accept answer later after check.

Answer (score -5):

To draw "outside the view" one should use `clipRect()` method. For example, in my case, I was to write `onDraw()` in the following way:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.clipRect(new Rect(-100,-100,100,100), Region.Op.UNION);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 100, circlePaint);
}
```

Comment: You are going to run into issues by using this technique. For instance, every time you need the view to redraw, the section of the screen outside of your view will not be redrawn which will cause various artifacts. There are various hacks you could use to work around this problem but the best solution is to draw your circle entirely inside your View.

Comment: You said I can't draw outside my view, not that it is possible but not good. You were wrong. It is better to accept this rather than giving me minuses. I am just learning Android and my questions are just to know truth.

Comment: It might be useful for you to know that Romain wrote a large portion of the Android platform code in action when you do this. He *is* the source of truth on this topic. :) We're trying to tell you why you're seeing what you're seeing, and why basing your future development on these flawed assumptions will get you into trouble down the road if you try to rely on them.

Comment: You cannot indeed draw outside of your view without resorting to such hacks. And unless you truly understand all the implications for the rendering system I would highly recommend you did not do this. It is much easier, safer and more efficient to do it the way I suggested above.

Comment: With all my respect to Romain, if he would tell me how to do what I want but also said that it is not recommended, I would accept the answer. But he just posted some minor fix in main answer and supported @Warpzit who told that my goal is unreacheable. Which was just wrong.

Comment: @Romain, why do you call my code "a hack"? I see no limitations on clipping rectangle components being negative. So, my `clipRect()` call is absolutely legal.

Comment: @Romain, I really saw some artifacts over activity title. This means that I should maintain global clipping area myself which is pity. Anyway I don't see any logical reasons yet why translation should have such an effect.

Comment: I gave you the proper solution: just set your circle's center to 100,100 instead. This will do what you want.

Comment: It won't do what I want since I don't want just to draw a circle. Circle is just an example. I want to draw game map and was thinking to use `setTranslate` methods to position it. I was not expecting `setTranslate` methods designed such unintuitive way.

Comment: What you are suggesting is "I have this piece of paper, but it can't fit everything, so I really want to draw outside this piece of paper". The answer isn't to draw outside the paper, its to make sure the paper is the size you need it to be in the first place. If the View for your game is going to fill the "game area" than you shouldn't have a problem using setTranslate. Maybe you should set a background to your view to see how much of the screen your CentralCircle view is really using.

Comment: If it is prohibited to draw outside the paper then why such drawing commands do not throw IndexOutOfBoundsException or prohibited in other way? Why it is not prohibited to extend clip area beyond the limits?

Comment: Because you are still drawing to a valid part of the canvas, just a part of the canvas you don't actually own. To continue the paper example, its as if your piece of paper is attached to a book. Sure you can write to the previous page, but somebody else owns that and can just override anything you have done. You will come to find there is a lot of things in the world of programming you CAN do. But just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Is this mean that android has one single canvas for all views?

Comment: I can't presume to know the internals, but, it makes sense. Each activity has a root view. The onDraw of that root view is going to have a canvas that is most of the screen. It then likely delegates its draw calls to each of its child views with a clipped Canvas. Again, though, that shouldn't be something you are thinking about. You may want to read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html. There are also a number of Android game tutorials on the net.